# How can I open a specific worksheet using VBA code on a command button macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering how can I open a specific worksheet using VBA code on a command button macro? When then user accesses my "Welcome Sheet" worksheet and clicks on the command button "Students" this should bring them to the "Students" worksheet.

I tried the following code but I got an invalid syntax error message as you can see in this [image.](https://ibb.co/sWGKqRp) Furthermore, some of the code turned to a red code and also one line had a yellow background effect as you can see in this [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYEmG.jpg)

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_2Click()
Sheets("Students").Activate
End Sub
```

Incase you wanted to check the command button macro is called the same name as written in the code my excel worksheet is linked below. However, I did check and to me it's all correct.

[Video](https://streamable.com/s/984qm/xmsmqv) of me showing I have a worksheet called "Students" and I have correctly set up the command button correctly.

Comment: Try `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Students").Select`

Comment: Syntax error @EmilyAlden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Students").Activate
End Sub
```

should do the trick. Remember to fully qualify your references (E.g. Workbook --> Sheet here), it'll save you headaches later!

Comment: Thank you, I was using the wrong type of bracket symbol.

Comment: @LiamDocherty I guess you have typed the name of the sub manually and it seems it should be `CommandButton2_Click()`